# PHP Paypal IPN Does not return anything in sandbox

Tags: php, paypal

Im currently developing a website where you can checkout with paypal. Everything is workign except the IPN after payment is not returning anything.

When i do it with the IPN Simulator it works perfectly, i'm printing the POST array into a text file for testing.

But when i pay through paypal sandbox and i receive Payment Successful the IPN does not seem to get anything at all.

Does the Paypal Sandbox Support IPN? Or is the IPN Simulator the only thing to test the IPN.

Comment: Yes the sandbox supports IPN.  Is your IPN return page set correctly on the Sandbox account?  
And is your development website accessible from the web? IPN won't work on localhost.

Comment: The IPN doesn't even return a HTTP Reponse Code. Just Empty, i have entered the correct url which can be accessed over the entire web. Its like paypal cant connect to my website.

Comment: If you look at the IPN history in your seller account can you see the transactions there?

Comment: Yes, they are all failed. I didnt get any HTML Response code. But if i enter a random website, i get a response code. I already checked my firewall on my server and tried several proxies to connect to the IPN and both are fine. Only paypal is having troubles.

Comment: Do your server logs show the attempt by IPN to access your program?  Also can your IPN program post back to PayPal for the validation step?

Comment: No. In htaccess log there is no Paypal IP address, i also log every access attempt to the IPN with REMOTE_ADDR and there is no paypal ip either.

Comment: Your firewall isn't blocking the PayPal Sandbox IP addresses is it?  Do your firewall logs show anything from 173.0.82.126 or 173.0.82.77?  https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/250/

Comment: No, i searched for the IP in the blacklist and nothing was found. I even tried to shutdown the firewall for a couple of minutes just to try.

Comment: I'm afraid that is my knowledge exhausted; sorry I couldn't help